# Javascript: Save a text/blob to a file using FileSaver.js

Tags: javascript, html, button, filesaver.js

I have built 2 buttons **Yes** and **No**.

I want to save the answer in a file: **Yes** or **No** (of course depend on the button that the end-user will press)

I've already used the Javascript object **blob** but is not working:

> The file  *testfile1.txt* **wasn't generated**.

I have a subfolder (inside my main folder) named  *js* in which I have the file *FileSaver.js*.

For this reason, I have:

```
`src="js/FileSaver.js"`
```

Implemented in my code. Below my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/FileSaver.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<button id="save-btn"> yes </button>
<button id="save-btn1"> no </button>
<script>
$("save-btn").click(function{

var blob= new Blob(["yes"],
{type:"text/plain;charset=utf-8"}
);
saveAs(blob,"testfile1.txt");
});
$("save-btn1").click(function{

var blob= new Blob(["no"],
{type:"text/plain;charset=utf-8"}
);
saveAs(blob,"testfile1.txt");
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're going to have to share the content of `FileSaver.js`, or at least the function definition for `saveAs()`.

Comment: Hi @BenM of course, I will add it.

Comment: **Danger** jQuery 1.9.1 has [known security issues](https://snyk.io/test/npm/jquery/1.9.1). The jQuery 1.x series is **no longer supported**. It does not get security fixes. Upgrade to a supported version of jQuery.

Comment: [not working](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) isn't a useful description of the problem. What happens? How is this different from what you expect? What error messages are reported in the Console of the Developer Tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this out.

I did a modification to your code this way.

*** Note : I imported the `FileSaver.js` [(downloaded from here)](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/master/src/FileSaver.js) and wrote the button click functions in a different js file (test.js)

This is my code and using this I am able to download a text file with input data each time when I click on the Yes or No button.

> test.html

```
<head>
<body>
    <button type="button" id="yesButton" value="Yes" onclick="saveYesInputDatataToFile();">Yes</button>
    <button type="button" id="noButton" value="No" onclick="saveNoInputDataToile();">No</button>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
    <script src="FileSaver.js"></script>
</body>
</head>
```

> test.js

```
function saveYesInputDatataToFile() {
    var userInput = document.getElementById("yesButton").value;
    var blob = new Blob([userInput],
    { type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8" });
    saveAs(blob, "userInput.txt");
}

function saveNoInputDataToile() {
    var userInput = document.getElementById("noButton").value;
    var blob = new Blob([userInput],
    { type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8" });
    saveAs(blob, "userInput.txt");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement you function as bellow:

```
let content = 'abc';
const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([content], {type: 'text/plain'}));
const link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = url;
link.setAttribute('download', 'log.txt'); //or any other extension
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
```

I've tested it in my chrome broswer.